# Scripts parsing performance issue after update Velocity version 1.6 to 2.3

Tags: velocity

We have problems after update velocity 1.6.3 to 2.3 version with parsing performance of the scripts which include many macros inside and overall lenght of the script is about 3000 lines.

Performance execution of this kind of scripts decreased 10 times, example script execution in velocity1 took: 1sec. and in velocity2:  6 to 10 seconds.

Did You observe such performance issues?

Can You suggest us a potential solution for this problem?

Some tips & tricks, maybe suggest some configuration change, share experience

Comment: Please provide e reproductible test, or do some profiling to point out the location for the regression. Otherwise it will be difficult to help.